# Wordpress - Validacion de formulario redirecciona a index dentro de la misma pagina

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Estoy haciendo la validacion del formulario de contacto en mi sitio
Intento validar via html, recaptcha, y en caso de exito por php antes de enviar.

De alguna manera, cuando el formulario es correcto (luego de html y recaptcha), en lugar de refrescar contact.php para validar con php, carga dentro de contact.php mi index.php! Como pista, les cuento que el index que carga dentro tiene el menu roto, solo aparece index (ninguna otra pagina creada dentro de wordpress)

Mi formulario contact.php:

```
<form action="" method="POST" >
          <h4>Get in <strong>touch</strong>.</h4>
          <div class="input-group margin-bottom-sm">
            <label for="name">Name</label><input type="text" name="name" placeholder="My name is..." required>
            <label for="email">eMail</label><input type="text" name="email" placeholder="My eMail is..." title="The domain portion of the email address is invalid (the portion after the @)." pattern="^([^\x00-\x20\x22\x28\x29\x2c\x2e\x3a-\x3c\x3e\x40\x5b-\x5d\x7f-\xff]+|\x22([^\x0d\x22\x5c\x80-\xff]|\x5c[\x00-\x7f])*\x22)(\x2e([^\x00-\x20\x22\x28\x29\x2c\x2e\x3a-\x3c\x3e\x40\x5b-\x5d\x7f-\xff]+|\x22([^\x0d\x22\x5c\x80-\xff]|\x5c[\x00-\x7f])*\x22))*\x40([^\x00-\x20\x22\x28\x29\x2c\x2e\x3a-\x3c\x3e\x40\x5b-\x5d\x7f-\xff]+|\x5b([^\x0d\x5b-\x5d\x80-\xff]|\x5c[\x00-\x7f])*\x5d)(\x2e([^\x00-\x20\x22\x28\x29\x2c\x2e\x3a-\x3c\x3e\x40\x5b-\x5d\x7f-\xff]+|\x5b([^\x0d\x5b-\x5d\x80-\xff]|\x5c[\x00-\x7f])*\x5d))*(\.\w{2,})+$" required>
            <label for="subject">Subject</label><input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="My message title is..." required>
            <label for="message">Message</label><textarea name="message" class="materialize-textarea" placeholder="My message is..." required></textarea>
          </div><!-- input group -->
          <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LflazgUAAAAANLnhAXhFn5qFWTER3yDAuDt_upj"></div>
          <div class="form-actions"><button type="reset" value="reset" class="btn white-grey"><i class="fa fa-close"></i> Reset</button> <button type="submit" value="submit" class="btn red-pink"><i class="fa fa-send-o"></i> Send</button></div>
      </form>
```

Alguna idea que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: Post it in spanish, this is not the english site. Otherwise your post will be closed as off topic.

Comment: Se necesita más código para poder ayudarte, una idea del entorno etc... ¿Donde pegas el HTML, por qué validas el email con una exp regular en vez de poner el input de type mail, que más procesos realizas en PHP? y la más básica de todas, ¿por que no usas un plugin como contact form 7 y evitas complicaciones?

Comment: gracias, no conocia el contacto form 7 y ya lo estoy implementando.
Queria realizar la rutina yo mismo ya que lo he hecho en el pasado y queria refrescar conocimientos. Pero sera para otro momento, ahora el tiempo me apremia. gracias de nuevo